# Is there any method to get chrome media exceptions

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

Google Chrome has a list called Media Exceptions, it contains sites or domains that the browser allow or block to use microphone or camera.

Is there any method to know whether a site already exist in the list and what the permission is ?